# How do I remove a Chatsworth 1928 Traditional 3TH Crosshead bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, removal

I have leaky faucet and would like to remove the faucet handle so I can gain access to the cartridge so I can replace it.

Here is the faucet:
[image: Chatsworth 1928 Traditional 3TH Crosshead bathroom faucet]

I am unable to use a razor blade to get under the button to pop it out.  It doesn't actually look like the button can pop out although I know some faucets have a button that pops out.  I assume I do not need to completely remove the faucet just to get access to the cartridge since two other brands of faucets that I have repaired both had ways to unscrew the handle after removing the top/button.  If someone knows how to get the faucet handles off please let me know your secret.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Use a mirror to examine the underside of the handles. 2. Possibly one of the cross posts unscrews and reveals a set-screw. 3. Using the wrenching flats allows the handle and cartridge to be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to make progress using #1 and #2.  I never used a wrenching flat.  Is this the additional thing you can use with a wrench to grip a rounded surface?  It sounds like you are suggesting the complete removal of the faucet to gain access to the cartridge.  Is that correct?  I guess I could go under the sink and remove the faucet although I am uncertain if that is possible without first gaining access to a screw or something under the button on the top of the faucet.  I guess if this is the only option I will have to go down this road.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I was not suggesting removing the faucet. The "wrenching flats" are the hexagonal faces which a wrench would fit on. The existence of TWO sets of hexagonal flats suggests that if you would hold the lower, larger one with one wrench, you could unscrew the upper, smaller one with another wrench and so remove the stem.

Comment: Jim thank you for all of your help.  It turns out that on the top of the faucet right above the cross posts it is possible to unscrew it.  Once unscrewed the button is easily removed and then you get access to a screw that once removed allows you to remove the top part of the faucet.  Then I was able to remove the larger hexagonal flat bottom and I now see the cartridge which I assume needs to be replaced to fix the drip.  I think/hope the cartridge is reverse threaded and unscrews by turning it clockwise (not sure).  It is almost fused to the other part.  Wish me luck, and thanks again.

Comment: After watching a few videos on youtube it looks like I remove the cartridge by turning it counterclockwise like how I unscrew most things.  My first attempts to do this so far have failed.  Maybe the cartridge is rusted or fused so unscrewing it is proving to be a challenge.  I'm concerned if I force the issue that I will break the cartridge so I'm not sure about the wised way to proceed.  The drip is still slow so I don't need to rush into this.  Anyway, wish me luck.  Thanks.